# Wait for Twitter's API limit to reset before continuing

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have the code below but I keep hitting the API limit when muting more than 200 accounts followed by the API limit error. I wanted to use 'wait_on_rate_limit' to make it continue once Twitter's limit has reset but the below code still comes up with the same error

```
import tweepy
import time

consumer_key = *****
consumer_secret = *****
key = *****
secret = *****


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

user_name = 'twitteruser'

def mute():
    followers = api.followers_ids(user_name)
    for x in followers:
        api.create_mute(x) 
        print ('muted follower')

while True:
    mute()
    time.sleep (300)
```

Is anyone able to help me so that the code will just continue running once the limit has been reset?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create_mute` function is not able to rely on a rate limit header that can be measured, as this is an account limit rather than an API limit (this is the case with most POST / create operations on the Twitter API). The per-user per-day/hour/minute mute limit is [not documented](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-limits). You'll have to put in some waits to try to manage this more slowly rather than blasting through all of the mutes in one go.

Comment: Thanks Andy, do you know if the mute limit is likely to follow the same 15 minute window for restarting?

Comment: And is there scope to increase this limit with the premium api?

Comment: the premium API only covers search, so no.